# get a dynamic value for css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new here so i'll ask. I have a dynamic slider that gets the height dynamically. So I need to get this dynamic *height* and pass the value to the top css.

I added this function in the *function.js* file

```
$('.navbar-inverse').css("top", 922);
```

and it gets the value, but I need this value to be dynamic and not inserted manually.

The height value comes from a class name `fs-stretcher`

Any help would be great. tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be part of an event handler if you want the dynamic value.  You call it a slider but I'm not sure what exactly the event is so we'll go with...scrolling down the page (just change the word `scroll` to whatever you use).

```
$('.navbar-inverse').on('scroll', function() {
    $(this).css('top', $('.fs-stretcher').height());
});
```

Comment: <div class=​"fs-stretcher" style=​"width:​ 1706px;​ height:​ 827.4100000000001px;​">​</div>​

Comment: And what does it say for `top` on the `navbar-inverse` that you want changed?

Comment: right now it get's the static value from the css stylesheet... 700px

Comment: But if i change the .fs-stretcher with the .slider, it get's the whole slider height that is over 4000px.

Comment: Post all your code, preferably into http://www.jsfiddle.com or http://www.codepen.io so I can see this

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('.navbar-inverse').css("top", $('.fs-stretcher').height())
```

Comment: it does not work. If i pass another value, like slider, it passes the value but not the real one... the real slider is 920 and it passes 4556

Comment: the real problem is that the height value of fs-stretcher is dynamic and you can see it only from the inspection panel in the html page. So it does not get the value.